# How to log the requests on specific port

Tags: logging, port, network-monitoring

I am running an application which is listening on specific port. I am looking for a solution to log the IP addresses and time of requests on the specific port in real time for weeks. I tried [Port Reporter](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9964) which was really good service except I couldn't filter data before logging it, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) which is also a good application except it doesn't log filtered data automatically and it uses tons of space to log raw data, and many other applications which didn't work as I desired.

I am using windows server 2003 R2, and I can use PID/Port/TCP to filter data.

Thanks in advance for solutions and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but as a fast suggestion it may help you:

[**CurrPorts**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) from nirsoft

Pls consider `Advanced Options` from `File` menu (Ctrl+O)

KvH ;)

Comment: Thanks body, I will look into it. Appreciate your kind response :D